# MomentJS.diff is not returning the correct number of months

Tags: momentjs, diff

I'm receiving from a certain API this timestamp, `1580844574000`, which is `02/04/2020`. When I run the below output,

```
moment().diff(moment(1580844574000), 'months')
```

I get 1 instead of 2, considering that today's date is April 2, 2020. I've also tried,

`moment('04/02/2020').diff(moment(1580844574000), 'months')` and I still get 1 instead of 2.

Is there something that I am doing wrong? I've put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xryqw0zc/), where you can see the output is returning 1 instead of 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because February 4 is not a full 2 months before April 2. Moment truncates the decimal places to return an integer by default (as opposed to rounding). From the moment docs:

> By default, moment#diff will truncate the result to zero decimal places, returning an integer. If you want a floating point number, pass true as the third argument. Before 2.0.0, moment#diff returned a number rounded to the nearest integer, not a truncated number.

So passing `true` as the third argument will give you the decimal places as well:

```
moment('04/02/2020').diff(moment(1580844574000), 'months', true)
// returns 1.9131457940991838
```

If you want to ignore the date part, you could use Moment's `month()` function and use normal subtraction:

```
moment('04/02/2020').month() - moment(1580844574000).month()
// returns 2
```